# Why does the following jquery tell me that my cookie still exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a loginform that uses a cookie to remember the state of the username-input and checkbox selections. I've implemented a button to reset the form like this:

```
<form id="login" action="~/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    ...
    <input id="formReset" type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-default"/>
</form>
```

I've implemented the jquery with alerts just to tell me what's going on. What I don't understand is that it always tell me that the cookie exists even though it does not show up when I inspect Resources -> Cookies in Chromes developer console. I know the cookie is being set if I login with the "Remember me" checkbox set to true, and it's being unset if I login again with the checkbox set to false.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#formReset').click(function() {
        if ($.cookie('loginCookie') === null || $.cookie('loginCookie') === "") {
            alert("Cookie does not exist");
        } else {
            // $.removeCookie('loginCookie');
            alert("Cookie does exist");
        }
        $(this).closest('form')("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try:  if (!$.cookie('loginCookie')) {} instead of your if

Comment: Are you sure your `=== null` check works? couldn't it be `undefined` as well? (I suppose, but no js wizard, that `== null` would be more correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Strict equal operator, for a cookie item that doesn't exist `$.cookie` returns `undefined`, so the condition fails, try using negation operator instead:

```
if (!$.cookie('loginCookie'))
```